# Distribution for time between arrivals at the same location by the same entity

Tags: time-series, distributions, poisson-distribution

Given a sample of inter arrival times for an entity at the same location, is there a distribution that can fit such a sample?. I was thinking about poisson, but was concerned about the independence, since the next arrival may be dependent on the previous arrival time.

Or is using a time series approach better to capture trend and seasonality?.

Comment: Poisson is discrete, and is normally used for counts (0,1,2, ...). *Times* are usually continuous, so the Poisson would not typically be suitable. You might consider something like a shifted exponential or a gamma distribution. While the time of the next arrival is obviously dependent on the time of the previous arrival, serial dependence in *inter*-arrival times would occur if the current *gap* in arrival times was related to the previous *gap* in arrival times. Possible, certainly, but not as obviously true. If there is such dependence, you'll likely want to model it, maybe via time series.

Comment: If you have such a sample, you can assess the suitability of say a gamma model of interarrival times with perhaps a [gamma probability plot](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/apr/section1/apr165.htm) (QQ plot), or by comparing a histogram with a fitted disribution, or some measure of goodness of fit. Another possibility would be to see if the cube root was close to normal. You can check for a shifted exponential by subtracting the smallest observation from all the others and checking an exponential QQ plot. You could check for serial dependence by looking at an ACF